# EpicEditor: update database

Tags: epiceditor

I have 3 EpicEditors on my webpage, each containing text related to an attribute of an object in my database. When I update the text, I see that the localStorage gets updated. But what I want to do is to save the changes to my database.

From the documentation, there is an exportFile event:

```
syncWithServerBtn.onclick = function () {
  var theContent = editor.exportFile();
  saveToServerAjaxCall('/save', {data:theContent}, function () {
    console.log('Data was saved to the database.');
  });
}
```

How does this work? Is there really a syncWithServer button? All I see are the preview and fullscreen buttons.

I suppose it means I must have a '/save' route in my views. How can I access theContent (the updated content) in this view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, syncWithServer is just an example if you had a button that did that. In the example, when you click the made up button it grabs the editor contents and then sends it to the DB with a fake saveToServerAjaxCall method. EpicEditor does nothing special for the server. This example is just showing a simple process of getting it there.

Comment: So, I need to create a button that when clicked, gets the contents and sends it to the DB through an Ajax call. Is that right?  Does exportFile work then? Or is it also a fake method?

Comment: Also, I noticed an update event in the docs. When does an update event occur? Would it be possible to update the database through Ajax everytime an update event happens?

Comment: @bard The example you posted is from the exportFile docs, so yeah, it's a real method :P. Update happens whenever the doc changes. So, if you press a key that generates a character (i.e. NOT ctrl, alt, etc, but a-z, 0-9 and so on) it'll trigger an update. I would _not_ fire an ajax event for _every_ update because it'll be sending tons of requests and get backed up. I suggest debouncing the save requests off of the `update` event. http://underscorejs.org/#debounce (example of debounce, but you dont need underscore, just a good explanation)

Answer (score 0):

I have given a detailed answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/35285968/936494. demonstrating how we can use a button on a form to submit the EpicEditor contents. The button click event code shown in the example can be used as reference to bind event on any desired button on the page and submit the contents. Hope it helps.