# Getting Epiceditor to work in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, epiceditor

I am trying to use epiceditor in a basic Ruby on Rails application. I followed the instructions on the webpage http://epiceditor.com/#. The epic editor window is not displaying for some reason...thanks

This is how I set up the code on my edit.html.erb view:

```

```
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
   <script src="js/epiceditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="epiceditor"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var editor = new EpicEditor().load();
</script>

<h1>Edit Wiki</h1>

  <%= form_for @mywiki do |f| %>
    <div>
        <%= f.label :title %>
        <%= f.text_field :title, :size => 75 %>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%= f.label :body %>
        <%= f.text_area :body, :rows => "35", :cols => "75" %>
    </div>

    <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

```

Answer (score 1):

is there some valid CSS added?

After adding the css from epic editor's site, I got it working.

Comment: I haven't added any CSS. Can you link where you saw to add the CSS? Thanks

Comment: It's in the fiddle. And on the Epic Editor Website, using the webdeveloper of your favorite browser, they are listed under "sources". Edit: Sorry, i liked the fiddle wrong. once http://epiceditor.com/ is online again, check the sources or the html source code for the linked css

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/OscarGodson/EpicEditor/tree/develop/epiceditor/themes

Answer (score 0):

Ruby  - 2.3.0
Rails - 4.2.5
Bootstrap 3 `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'`
EpicEditor `gem 'epic-editor-rails'`

- Ran bundle from my app root:

`rails_app_root$ bundle`

- Updated **/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss**

  @import 'base/epiceditor';
  //@import 'preview/bartik';
  //@import 'preview/github';
  //@import 'preview/preview-dark';
  //@import 'editor/epic-dark';
  //@import 'editor/epic-light';

  // This is shown here for reference just to instruct that I have imported EpicEditor themes first.
  @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
  @import "bootstrap";

  Note I have just imported **base/epiceditor** and others are commented out. The reason being they were overriding the Bootstrap styling which wasn't needed.
- On my form partial `/app/views/.../_form.html.haml` under <form> element following things I added:

  ```
  #myTextAreaContainer(style='display: none')
    = text_area_tag("body", myText, id: 'myTextArea')

  .form-group
    = label_tag(nil, "My Text", class: "col-md-3 control-label")
    #myTextEpicEditor.col-md-7
  ```
- On my show view `/app/views/..../show.html.haml`

  ```
  .row
    .col-md-10
      #myDetailsView.form-horizontal

        %div(style='display: none')
          = text_area_tag("myText", @my_text, id: 'viewMyTextTextArea')

        .form-group
          = label_tag(nil, "My Text", class: "col-sm-3 control-label")
          #viewMyTextBodyEpicEditor.col-sm-6
  ```
- In /app/assets/javascripts/custom.js

  ```
    (function ($) {

      isEmptyValue = function(value) {
        return ( undefined === value || null === value || "" === value || ("" === value.replace(/[\n\r]/g, '')) )
      }

      myForm = function() {
        return $("form#myForm");
      };

      // Note: EpicEditor requires just the id value not a jquery selector
      // like "#myTextEpicEditor"
      myFormEpicEditorContainerId = function() {
        return "myTextEpicEditor";
      }

      // Note: EpicEditor requires just the id value not a jquery selector
      // like "#myTextArea"
      myFormTextAreaId = function() {
        return "myTextArea";
      }

      myFormMyTextLocalStorageName = function() {
        return "myTextEpicEditorLocalStorage";
      }

      myFormMyTextBodyFileName = function() {
        return "myTextFile";
      }

      myFormEpicEditorOpts = function() {
        var myTextEpicEditorOpts = {
          container: myFormEpicEditorContainerId(),
          textarea: myFormTextAreaId(),
          localStorageName: myFormMyTextLocalStorageName(),
          file: {
            name: myFormMyTextBodyFileName(),
            defaultContent: '',
            autoSave: 100
          },
        };
        return myTextEpicEditorOpts;
      }

      loadEpicEditorOnMyForm = function() {
        var selector = "#" + myFormEpicEditorContainerId();
        if ($(selector).length == 0) {
          return;
        }

        var myFormEpicEditorInstance = new EpicEditor(myFormEpicEditorOpts()).load();
      };

      bindClickEventOnSaveBtnOnMyForm = function() {
        var saveBtnObj = $("#saveBtn");

        if (saveBtnObj.length == 0) {
          return;
        }

        saveBtnObj.off("click").on("click", function(event) {
          var myFormObj = myForm();

          var myFormEpicEditorInstance = new EpicEditor(myFormEpicEditorOpts());

          // console.log(myFormEpicEditorInstance);

          var myText = myFormEpicEditorInstance.exportFile(myFormMyTextBodyFileName(), 'text');

          // console.log(myText);

          if (isEmptyValue(myText)) {
            alert("Please enter text");
            event.stopPropagation();
            return false;
          }

          myFormObj.submit();
        });
      };

      // Used for rendering EpicEditor in ONLY preview mode with only 
      // full screen button and when the epic editor is switched to 
      // full screen mode it hides the editor pane. 
      displaySavedMyTextPreview = function() {
        var myDetailsView = $("#myDetailsView")

        if (myDetailsView.length == 0) {
          return;
        };

        var viewMyTextEpicEditorOpts = {
          container: 'viewMyTextBodyEpicEditor',
          textarea: 'viewMyTextTextArea',
          button: {
            preview: false,
            edit: false,
            fullscreen: true,
            bar: "auto"
          },
        };

        var viewMyTextEpicEditorInstance = new EpicEditor(viewMyTextEpicEditorOpts);
        viewMyTextEpicEditorInstance.load(function() {
          console.log("loaded");
          viewMyTextEpicEditorInstance.preview();
        });

        viewMyTextEpicEditorInstance.on('fullscreenenter', function() {
          // console.log("full screen enter");
          $(viewMyTextEpicEditorInstance.getElement('editorIframe')).hide();
        });
      };


    }) (jQuery);

    var ready;

    ready = function() {
      loadEpicEditorOnMyForm();
      bindClickEventOnSaveBtnOnMyForm();
      displaySavedMyTextPreview();
    };

    $(document).ready(ready);
    $(document).on('page:load', ready);
  ```

**Note**

- The code shown above is working code. In case it doesn't work for you try looking for any mistakes made in typing the element selectors etc.
- I assume that jQuery is available in the application.
- Though I have not tried it but you can include multiple EpicEditors on the same page by passing in custom options like I have demonstrated.